# assert test failed in async() assertion with QUnit testing

Tags: javascript, tdd, qunit

I am Testing My code Using TDD.

code is as follow -

```
 QUnit.test("Testing submitApi", function (assert) {
        //  createSampleSheet();          
        BWUser.authenticate().done(function () {
            BWTableProperties.readAllTableProperties().then(function (allTableProperties) {

                for (var i = 0; i < allTableProperties.length; i++) {                        
                    var getResult = Submit.submitApi(allTableProperties[i], "test", 0); //getResult is Promise
                    getResult.then(function () {
                        var promise = assert.async();
                        var promisedone = makeQuerablePromise(getResult);// gives whether promise resolved or not
                        promisedone.then(function () {

                            assert.equal(promisedone.isFulfilled(), true, "Promise should be resolved");
                            promise();
                        });
                    });                     
                }

            });
        });
    });
```

when i Run the test it shows following Error :

> `Expected at least one assertion, but none were run - call expect(0)
>   to accept zero assertions.`

can anybody suggest what went wrong here, first impression i feel that because of for loop there may be error but i'm not sure. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `assert.async` when already inside asynchronous code. If you call it at the beginning of the test, before the call to the async code, the test will wait for the `promise()` call.